# error driver.find_element or find_elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to click "Create New Network" by using selenium.

```
<button type="button" id="dt-refreshBtn" class="btn wc-btn--link" data-label="Create New Network" role="link"><span class="icon-button" data-testid="dnxButton-iconButtonContainer" data-awt="networkListing-button-createNew"><i class="dnac-icon-add-circle" data-testid="dnxButton-icon" title="Create New Network"></i><span class="dnx-btn-icon-label" data-testid="dnxButton-iconLabel">Create New Network</span></span></button>
<span class="icon-button" data-testid="dnxButton-iconButtonContainer" data-awt="networkListing-button-createNew"><i class="dnac-icon-add-circle" data-testid="dnxButton-icon" title="Create New Network"></i><span class="dnx-btn-icon-label" data-testid="dnxButton-iconLabel">Create New Network</span></span>
<i class="dnac-icon-add-circle" data-testid="dnxButton-icon" title="Create New Network"></i>
<span class="dnx-btn-icon-label" data-testid="dnxButton-iconLabel">Create New Network</span>
```

[image]

I tried several scripts to find the location of "Create New Network" button, but got failed with below reason.

1. Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
2. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
3. 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

here are scripts I've tried.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='Create New Network']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-awt='networkListing-button-createNew']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id='dt-refreshBtn']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='dnx-btn-icon-label']").click()
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='dnx-btn-icon-label']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn wc-btn--link']")[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dt-refreshBtn']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "dt-refreshBtn").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-testid='dnxButton-icon']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-testid='dnxButton-iconLabel']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-awt='networkListing-button-createNew']").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='Create New Network']").click()
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dt-refreshBtn']").click()
```

could you please help this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found the reason and got the solution in this code.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dt-refreshBtn' and @class='btn wc-btn--link']")
```

with this combination, it worked.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Now let's go through each error .find_elements() is used for multiple elements and .click() | send_keys() is used for a single element is why the majority will give **'list' object has no attribute 'click'** unless you access the individual element.

.send_keys() is normally used for input tags or textareas and you'd want .click() for the button tag.

Now some valid xpaths would be like so:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn wc-btn--link']").click()
```

would be a valid xpath if that is the only button class with that class name.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dt-refreshBtn']").click()
```

**If this still doesn't find check if the element is under iframes or shadow roots.**

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
but now I got this error with driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn wc-btn--link']").click()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/onboarding/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 445, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='btn wc-btn--link']"}

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dt-refreshBtn']").click()
```

should work

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
but now I got this error with driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dt-refreshBtn']").click() 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/onboarding/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@id='dt-refreshBtn']"}